# Getting text/attributes from a script object function in html using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been doing web scraping on a website where I need to get the javascript so I could extract data such as name, created date, and some randomly generated codes as will be shown below...

Is there an efficient/any way of getting text/attributes from a script object function in a `<script type="text/javascript">` from a html webpage.

I was able to find the script section using BeautifulSoup, with the function embedded in it is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//COMMENT// Some data already here

$(document).ready(function() {
    name.init("<website Link>")
    lang.init("en", "GB")
    data.init("hello", "", "AT3K21SDV", "YIERE34ITEW832WCNG3VMASJKHO345JKRELRK5", "")
});
</script>
```

Specifically, I need to get the `$(document).ready(function()` section that will include `AT3K21SDV` and `YIERE34ITEW832WCNG3VMASJKHO345JKRELRK5`.

I've been bugging my brains out trying to get it using index like so; `soup[3:40] but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beautifulsoup` doesn't parse JavaScript, so you need to use other tools. For example `re` to extract the information:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval


txt = '''<script type="text/javascript">

//COMMENT// Some data already here

$(document).ready(function() {
    name.init("<website Link>")
    lang.init("en", "GB")
    data.init("hello", "", "AT3K21SDV", "YIERE34ITEW832WCNG3VMASJKHO345JKRELRK5", "")
});
</script>'''

data = re.search(r'data\.init(\(.*?\))', txt).group(1)
data = literal_eval(data)

print(data[2], data[3])
```

Prints:

```
AT3K21SDV YIERE34ITEW832WCNG3VMASJKHO345JKRELRK5
```

---

EDIT: If inside `data.init(...)` are newlines, you must set `flags=re.DOTALL` in `re.search()`:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval


txt = '''<script type="text/javascript">

//COMMENT// Some data already here

$(document).ready(function() {
    ab.info.init("sv", "pp", "f", "NONE",
        "rw", "3r7u6565667",
        "3435345")
});
</script>'''

data = re.search(r'info\.init(\(.*?\))', txt, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
data = literal_eval(data)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
('sv', 'pp', 'f', 'NONE', 'rw', '3r7u6565667', '3435345')
```

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` at the line `data = re.search(r'data\.init(\(.*?\))', txt).group(1)`
Because I already acquired the javascript section using BeautifulSoup, I did `txt = str(javaScriptData)` where `javaScriptData` contains that sectiom

Comment: @Legion If you get this error, then the variable `txt` doesn't contain string `data.init(...)`. You need to check for this possibility.

Comment: @Andej Kesely How about if the string was longer; `mywebsite.data.init(...)`, then the search I included was `re.search(r'mywebsite\.data\.init(\(.*?\))', txt).group(1)` which should be right.. not sure, but it may be because I used `BeautifulSoup` for the previous steps?

Comment: @Legion Yes, you can do that. There's site Regex101, where you can try your regexes: https://regex101.com/r/HjiiGF/1  Put the string and regex there and see if it works.

Comment: @Andej Kesely Its something to do with the indentation format (it sees it as a break in line as shown here [link](https://regex101.com/r/HjiiGF/3) . Is there a way to automatically reformat the code?

Comment: @Legion Yes, set `flags=re.DOTALL` in `re.search()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Andej Kesely I used the way which worked: `txt = str(javaScriptData).replace('\n', '')` which worked as well. Thanks for the great help